# Чем отличается сложный союз от составного?

Tags: союзы

приведите примеры обоих и объясните в чем различие(в интернете не могу найти)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информация из первого источника ([Русская корпусная грамматика](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7#112)), по запросу "сложные союзы", говорит о том, что это одно и то же:

> ***1.1.2. Сложные, или составные, союзы***
>
> Сложные, или составные, союзы состоят из двух и более слов, которые семантически представляют собой одну единицу. В образовании большинства составных союзов участвуют:
>
> - простые союзы (*и, что, чем, как, когда, чтобы, если, только*), см. п. 1.1.2.1;
> - предлоги (ср. *несмотря* > *несмотря на то что, вопреки* > *вопреки тому что*), см. п. 1.1.2.2;
> - частицы (ср. *бы* > *если бы*, не > *пока не*), см. п. 1.1.2.3;
> - наречия (ср. *даром* > *даром что, скоро* > *коль скоро*), см. п. 1.1.2.4.;
> - местоимения (ср. *чем… тем*), см. п. 1.1.2.5;
> - существительные (ср. *правда*).

Answer (score 1):

Простые союзы делятся на элементарные и неэлементарные (сложные):

> § 1674. Простые (однословные) союзы неоднородны по своему формальному
> строению. Одни из них — элементарные — состоят, как правило, из одной
> фонемы или одного слога: а, и, ли, но, да, же, как, что, чем, ведь,
> лишь, хоть, пусть. Другие — неэлементарные — имеют более сложное
> строение. Среди них выделяется, с одной стороны, группа союзов,
> которые исторически восходят к соединениям двух или более служебных
> слов (или служебного слова с застывшей формой знаменательного слова),
> но в современном языке не членятся на морфемы; таковы абы, дабы,
> чтобы, якобы, ибо, или, итак, либо, если, ежели, нежели, сиречь,
> будто. С другой стороны, многие союзы неэлементарной структуры (и их
> аналоги) сохраняют живые

Составные союзы это все непростые союзы:

> § 1673. По своему строению все союзы делятся на простые
> (однословные) и составные (неодпословные).